# How to select names of fonts, which were used in text document (in richTextBox) and to transmit names of fonts to textBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, richtextbox

How do I select names of fonts, which were used in text document (in richTextBox) and transmit them to a textBox? But only those fonts which were used in text.

Answer (score 0):

You are gonna need to parse the rich text to find the fonts. You can find it in the `RichTextBox.rtf` property.

Here is an example of Rich Text with multiple fonts :

```
{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\deflang3084
    {\\fonttbl
        {\\f0\\fnil\\fcharset0 Bell MT;}
        {\\f1\\fnil\\fcharset0 Calibri;}
        {\\f2\\fnil\\fcharset0 Broadway;}
        {\\f3\\fnil\\fcharset0 Elephant;}
        {\\f4\\fnil\\fcharset0 DejaVu Sans Condensed;}
        {\\f5\\fnil\\fcharset0 Kristen ITC;}
        {\\f6\\fnil\\fcharset0 Niagara Engraved;}
        {\\f7\\fnil\\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}
    }\r\n\\viewkind4\\uc1\\pard\\sa200\\sl276\\slmult1\\lang12
        \\f0\\fs22 Salut les amis\\f1\\par\r\n\\f2 un\\f1\\par\r\n\\f3 
        mot dans\\f1\\par\r\ndes \\f4 fonts \\f1\\par\r\n\\f5 
        diff\\'e9rentes\\f1\\par\r\n\\pard\\f6
        blablabla\\lang3084\\f7\\fs17\\par\r\n}\r\n
```

As you can see, at the beginning of the document, there is a `fonttbl` "tag" with all the different fonts used.

I'll leave the parsing logic to you. I'm sure you can figure it out as they are logically enclosed between brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Regex:

```
\\fcharset\d+ (.+);
```

And here's a sample:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\\fcharset\d+ (.+);");
List<string> fonts = new List<string>();
foreach(Match m in r.Matches(richTextBox1.Rtf))
{
    fonts.Add(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```